# Note onset detection from audio

Tags: java, matlab, audio, onset-detection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Note onset detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294468/note-onset-detection)

I need a note onset detector quite robust for my thesis work in Java/Matlab.
From an audio file I extract the loudness and some other (kind of) features which I need, but the onset problem is still a hard one and, most of the time, not exactly done.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Midi is not concerned!

INPUT: audio signal with a bass line (from a file or line input)

BACKGROUND: I need to do it in real time...so the other questions are irrelevant.

Comment: Onset detection is quite a wide topic, it depends on the acoustic content of the audio data (music? speech? noise? etc.) and on the application.

Comment: Yes, it would be a good idea to describe which content you want to process.

Comment: audio signal with a bass line

Comment: need to do the process in real time

Comment: only bass playing or other instruments as well?

Comment: Only bass playing and in REAL TIME...this is the difference with other topics...can't close my question...