# Audio Separation of .wav signal

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I have read the following question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294468/note-onset-detection/294724#294724)

What I am attempting to do is take a signal (.wav audio file) which contains calls from different Bat species. Here is a graph representation of the signal:

[image]

What I have done so far is:

1) Emphasise the signal

2) Compress the signal

This is the output I got plotted:

[image]

I need to remove the signals that do not warrent consideration. At the moment, the signal is in a 1D representation, and, after the Separation has been completed the signal will be a 2D representation containing JUST the calls, thus I can perform analysis on each of the calls.

This is my suggested methodology to do this:

1) Split the signal into blocks of: 256x100 (so they overlap)

2) Calculate the RMS (Root-mean-square) of each of the blocks

3) Compare (2) to a threshold value, and, if the block warrants consideration then this can be classed as a call.

But the problem is this:

1) Will splitting the signal into blocks of 256x100 go over the calls and thus making some of the calls lost when calculating the RMS?

2) How do I therefore pick a suitable threshold value? Would finding the peaks in the signal be an accurate assumption for this?

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about signal processing (probably better-suited for http://dsp.stackexchange.com).


Comment: @OliCharlesworth I asked on there too :) DSP doesn't get updated very often and there are some people on S/O with DSP knowledge who might not visit the site.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to both lists.

Comment: @BjornRoche My bad. I'm just trying to get a solution to the problem that I'm facing

Comment: Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a median filter - medfilt1() if you are using matlab. This will allow you to remove outlier, which is what you are trying to do here. You may set the window size you would like and it sets the values to a median of each window, which should be close to the real value if you don't have outliers.

If the data get's too corrapted you may want to consider a the 6 sigma method, where instead of calculating the RMS you calculate variance and remove data points which are beyond +-3 standard deviations.